# Multiple Download files from internet on multiple button clicks in windows phone 8 and show saperate progress or Progressbar

Tags: windows-phone-8, listbox, progress-bar, transfer, bdmultidownloader

I am working on windows phone 8 and i trying to download multiple files through multiple buttons from the ListBox of windows phone 8. I want to show the individual progresses in my listBox. How is this possible ? if you have any answer than please reply.

I have found one solution like [TransferControl](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/tutorial) which has the capability to pause and resume the download in windows phone 8 but i am unable to implement on that so if you have the proper tutorial except this link than please give me the link.

OR

suggest me what the way me should follow to show individual progress in listbox after button_click in windows phone 8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Creating download queue would be better if you think and perform download one by one because if you will give download request of two or more download and both are in progress then ProgressChange event will fire for both download request so no appropriate progress can get.

Although if you provide separate progress change handler for each request then you can download multiple file with progressbar.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for reply, but in my case i can not assign saperate progress change handler because i am downloading multiple files from the ListBox of wp8 in that i my download buttons are generating randomely associated with link so if according to you i will assign saparate progress change handler for every button than it will not good way to do it if my ListBox has the 1000 download button than me have to assign 1000 progress changed handler.

Comment: You are right Ashish and that's why I suggested making download queue.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Have you any example or link for create Download Queue for my scenario ? i mean it will help me good start for work on Download Queue.

Comment: Use http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61 sample, check discover upload request at the time of navigation. It check all active downloads if available then start showing its progress. You can add request here in List of download available-

Comment: I don't have my own example, but I am sure you can understand this sample from Microsoft.

Comment: Here is BackgroundTransfer link for phone http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Transfer-ce07e86f